# Is it forbidden for a man to sleep on his stomach?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, sleep, tractate-brachot

We learned in Brachot 13b that R' Yehoshua ben Levi "cursed one who sleeps perakdan".

There is a disagreement among the rishonim as to what perakdan means(face-up according to Rashi, Tosafot; face-down according to He'aruch, R' Chananel, and Tur; or either according to Rambam, Rashba, Meiri, and Tur. See Choshvei Shemo pg. 52).

For kriat shema, both positions are forbidden to recite it in(Shulchan Aruch OC 63:1).

Is R' Yehoshua ben Levi's(zachur letov!) statement l'halacha? And if so, according to which definition?

I think the answer lies in the reason for the "curse". I'm interested in what people's learning brings up.

Comment: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/02/sleeping-on-left-or-right-side.html

Comment: @JoelK Great article! Same question.

Comment: Nice pun. The answer "lies"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed brought down by some as the Halacha, and in practice, both positions (face up and face down) are forbidden.

See the [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 71:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.71.5?with=all&lang=bi):

> וְצָרִיךְ לִזָּהֵר מְאֹד לְהַרְגִּיל אֶת עַצְמוֹ לִשְׁכַּב עַל צִדּוֹ. וְאִסּוּר גָּדוֹל לִשְׁכַּב פְּרַקְדָּן, דְּהַיְנוּ גַּבּוֹ לְמַטָּה וּפָנָיו לְמַעְלָה, אוֹ בְּהִפּוּךְ פָּנָיו לְמַטָּה וְגַבּוֹ לְמַעְלָה, אֶלָּא דַּוְקָא עַל צִדּוֹ
>
> … You should take great care to get yourself into the habit of lying
>   on your side. It is strictly forbidden to lie in a supine position,
>   that is your back downward and your front [facing] upward, or
>   conversely—your front downward and your back upward, but only on your
>   side. …

This is also mentioned by the [Mishnah Berurah in 239:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.239.1?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.239.6&lang2=bi).

Comment: Not everyone agrees with this, see [Misgeres HaShulchan 71:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9214&st=&pgnum=185).

Comment: @Ploni Fair enough, but is there ever any Halacha anywhere that everyone agrees to? :) Edited the Kitzur into the answer, so updated the first sentence as well to limit the Halachah to 'some'.

Comment: @Ploni, excuse me but nowhere in that misgeres hashulchan does he argue on the halacha, he just says that Rambam lists that halacha in his hilchos refuah.

Comment: Source for the kitzur, Chaei Adam 35:5.